# Structs from one header into a struct in another header

Tags: c, header, struct

I'm having trouble on this...
I have this header:

```
#ifndef PESSOA_H
#define PESSOA_H

typedef struct pa{
    int idade;
    int atend;
}pessoa;


void inicPessoa(pessoa *ps, int id);

#endif
```

and, in filaC.h:

```
#ifndef FILAC_H
#define FILAC_H

#include "pessoa.h"

typedef struct pessoa elem_t;

typedef struct no{
  elem_t info;
  struct no *prox, *ant;
} No;

typedef No * Fila;
#endif
```

but compiler says fiel info on filaC.h has an incomplete type.

changing `elem_t info;` to `struct elem_t into;` had no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no type called `struct pessoa`.  You have `struct pa`, and you have `pessoa` (a typedef).

So you need to change this:

```
typedef struct pessoa elem_t;
```

into one of:

```
typedef struct pa elem_t;
typedef pessoa elem_t;
```